# QGIS: Error [24]: The following signature does not match the band set. MC_ID: 1 C_ID: 1

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2, image-classification, scp

I have run my classification map in QGIS using the semi-automatic classification plugin or SCP.
I want to use the same ROIs for different sentinel imageries. But I faced an error

> Error [24]: The following signature does not match the band set. MC_ID: 1 C_ID: 1

How can I use the same ROIs for different band sets?